# No input file specified apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu

i using lamp and im geting no input error when im trying to add a new php file to me website folder i try to research it but didn't fix it
this me htaccess file

```
  <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride all
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
            # Uncomment this directive is you want to see apache2's
            # default start page (in /apache2-default) when you go to /
            #RedirectMatch ^/$ /apache2-default/
    </Directory>
```

i installed this already `sudo a2enmod rewrite`

thanks
miki

Comment: You can't put `<directory>` into htaccess, only in the apache config files. Please post the rewriterules you are trying to get to work. Also add some punctuation to you question, as it's not very readable at the moment.